# Why are the coefficients of vectors (that are not eigenstates) the probability amplitudes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, linear-algebra

In the adiabatic approximation, we assume that: [image]

are the solutions of the eigenvalue problem:
[image]

We know however that the ψn(t) 's here may not be actual solutions to the time dependent Schrodinger equation. Nevertheless, we write the solution of time-dependent SH as a linear combination of ψn's and then we interpret the coefficients to be the probability amplitudes.

But why? The vectors in the linear combination are not solutions to the time dependent SH equation. Does the Copenhagen interpretation allow that?

Comment: I assume by Copenhagen interpretation you mean Born rule.

Comment: Yes, Born's rule.